# Is there a default file upload size limit in django?

Tags: django, file

I am using django `FileField` and `ImageField` in my models but I am wondering is there any default upload size limit for files.I researched about it and I found that we can limit the file upload size to some size by configuring `MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE` in the project's `settings.py` but what If i didn't handle any validation for the Image/file field?Then will the user be able to upload image of any unlimited size  or is there any default size limit for this ?

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a setting for this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:string-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE

You should add (FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE) to your settings.py. The default value is 2.5MB.

Comment: `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` sets `The maximum size that an upload will be before it gets streamed to the file system.` so the user can still upload any size of file, it just not in memory but in filesystem

Answer (score 2):

There is no default size limit.

You should actually do :

> from django.conf import settings
>
> file._size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE